# Convert the NetCDF writing code from annual to monthly using 'datatime' library

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf, python-datetime

I have a NetCDF file of shape 180 x 360 x 720. Data is saved such that 180 refers to 12 months from '2001 to 2015', 360 and 720 refers to central latitudes and longitudes ranging from 89.75 degree to -89.75 degree and from -179.75 degree to 179.75 degree in 0.5 degree interval, respectively.

I want to write this to a NetCDF using `datetime` packages.

The code which I use for writing yearly data is mentioned below:

```py
import datetime
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
# -----------------------
nyears = 15;   ## From 2001-2015 but time axis is 180 in shape
unout = 'days since 2001-01-01 00:00:00'
# -----------------------
res = 0.5
lon = np.arange(-179.75,180,res);
lat = np.arange(-89.75,-90,res);

dataout = X; # create some random data
datesout = [datetime.datetime(2001+iyear,1,1) for iyear in range(nyears)]; # create datevalues
# =========================
ncout = Dataset('/home/chandra/data/Temp_data_evap/BESS_ET.nc','w','NETCDF4'); # using netCDF3 for output format 
ncout.createDimension('lon',nx);
ncout.createDimension('lat',ny);
ncout.createDimension('time',nyears);
lonvar = ncout.createVariable('lon','float32',('lon'));lonvar[:] = lon;
latvar = ncout.createVariable('lat','float32',('lat'));latvar[:] = lat;
timevar = ncout.createVariable('time','float64',('time'));timevar.setncattr('units',unout);timevar[:]=date2num(datesout,unout);
myvar = ncout.createVariable('Evaporation','float32',('time','lat','lon'));myvar.setncattr('units','mm');myvar[:] = dataout;
ncout.close();
```

Can someone help me convert the code from yearly to monthly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use number of months as the size of your time axis i.e the length of the dimension. So, if you have 15 years of monthly data, you have 15*12 = 180 values in time.

Here is the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import datetime
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
import numpy as np
# -------------------------------------------------
# Make date axis:
yystart = 2001
nyears = 15
monperyear = 12
ntime = nyears*monperyear
unout = 'days since 2001-01-01 00:00:00'
# -------------------------------------------------
res = 0.5
lon = np.arange(-179.75,180,res);nx=np.size(lon)
lat = np.arange(-89.75,90,res);ny=np.size(lat)

dataout = np.random.random((ntime,ny,nx))
datesout = [datetime.datetime(yy,mm,15,0) for yy in range(yystart,yystart+nyears) for mm in range(1,13)]
# =========================
ncout = Dataset('BESS_ET.nc','w','NETCDF4'); # using netCDF3 for output format 
ncout.createDimension('lon',nx);
ncout.createDimension('lat',ny);
ncout.createDimension('time',ntime);
lonvar = ncout.createVariable('lon','float32',('lon'));lonvar[:] = lon;
latvar = ncout.createVariable('lat','float32',('lat'));latvar[:] = lat;
timevar = ncout.createVariable('time','float64',('time'));timevar.setncattr('units',unout);timevar[:]=date2num(datesout,unout);
myvar = ncout.createVariable('Evaporation','float32',('time','lat','lon'));myvar.setncattr('units','mm');myvar[:] = dataout;
ncout.close();
```